# Display custom list of files in QTreeView using QFileSystemModel or QAbstractItemModel

Tags: python, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel, qfilesystemmodel, pyside6

I'm building an open source PySide6 app based on the custom file browser in `QTreeView`.
I've already subclassed `QFileSystemModel` to display a custom column with some extra data.

Now my goal is to display a specific subset of files (they can be located on different drives) in a treeview.

To simplify things imagine that I have a function:

```
def files_to_display():
    return ['C:\file1', 'D:\file2', 'D:\file3']
```

Now I need to display these files in my `QTreeView`. I tried using `QSortFilterProxyModel` and `filterAcceptsRow` to filter out everything else and it worked. However on a relatively large number of files it's extremely slow and unusable. I'm pretty sure a simpler custom file tree would work faster because afaik `QFileSystemModel` tracks the folder state and runs other extra stuff that I can live without.

I'm not sure how to solve this problem.
I see basically 2 ways:

1. Somehow cut out what I don't need from `QFileSystemModel`.
   With this solution I don't fully understand how I do this. In particular, how do I fill the model with the data from my function? How do it use `setRootPath`?
2. Subclass `QAbstractItemModel`.
   This solution is more or less clear, however, it's missing some of the important things that go with `QFileSystemModel` out of the box: I need the columns and the data it provides (name, size, type, modification date), I also need file/folder icons that I'm using with `QFileIconProvider`.

So basically I'd like to use a light-weighted version of `QFileSystemModel` without watching the file system and with my list of files.

I'm open to alternative solutions.

Comment: Did you try `QFileSystemModel.setNameFilters()`?

Comment: As far as I understand `setNameFilters` is used to filter by file name mask. That's not what I need exactly. Also looks like this operation is going to be heavy.